# How to return results from dataproc pyspark to jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to run pyspark on google cloud / dataproc. I am able to submit my job on the cluster and get results on the cluster. However, I want to get results back into jupyter notebook as a dataframe. My code to submit a pyspark job is as follows -

THis is a very standard function by google. Can you help me modify this to get the results of the job also back into jupyter?

THis is a code I am running on Jupyter to connect to pyspark cluster on dataproc

```
submit_pyspark_job(dataproc_cluster_client, project, region, cluster_name, bucket_name,
                       filename):

   """Submit the Pyspark job to the cluster (assumes `filename` was uploaded
    to `bucket_name."""
    job_details = {
        'placement': {

            'cluster_name': cluster_name
        },
        'pyspark_job': {
            'main_python_file_uri': 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, filename),
            'jar_file_uris':['gs://hadoop-lib/bigquery/bigquery-connector-hadoop2-0.13.9.jar']
        }
    }

    result = dataproc_cluster_client.submit_job(
        project_id=project, region=region, job=job_details)
    job_id = result.reference.job_id
    print('Submitted job ID {}.'.format(job_id))
    return job_id
```

This code runs well and submits my jobs to google clusters. Now, I want the results to come back to jupyter as a dataframe that I can later manipulate.

Comment: Where is your job writing the output? If it's e.g. in GCS, you should be able to retrieve the output files and load them into your notebook locally.

Comment: Yes, it is writing on the console of GCS. Would you know of a way to return/display the results in jupyter notebook?

Comment: Depending on your usecase, it may be easier to run Jupyter on dataproc cluster (Jupyter Optional component with Component Gateway). In which case you can use pyspark code directly in the nodebook and manipulate it via pandas and such.